# confuse about the Baxter joint trajectory program

Tags: ros, joint, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone

I currently was learning use simple Joint trajectory way to control the robot arm. The example shows in the Baxter wiki there the explain was a bit confuse for me. Here is the program:

```
def add_point(self, positions, time):
        point = JointTrajectoryPoint()
        point.positions = copy(positions)
        point.time_from_start = rospy.Duration(time)
        self._goal.trajectory.points.append(point)
```

this is the link of the example: [Joint Trajectory Client](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Joint_Trajectory_Client_-_Code_Walkthrough)

By the way, the example they had missing some of the code lines which was:

```
    print("Initializing node... ")
    rospy.init_node("rsdk_joint_trajectory_client_%s" % (limb,))
    print("Getting robot state... ")
    rs = baxter_interface.RobotEnable(CHECK_VERSION)
    print("Enabling robot... ")
    rs.enable()
    print("Running. Ctrl-c to quit")
    positions = {
        'left':  [-0.11, -0.62, -1.15, 1.32,  0.80, 1.27,  2.39],
        'right':  [0.11, -0.62,  1.15, 1.32, -0.80, 1.27, -2.39],
   }
```

And my question is why in the `add_point()` there have to use `copy(positions)` and at the end of function still have to use `append()` to add the point into the list again?

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236792/confuse-about-the-baxter-joint-trajectory-program/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lets take `add_point()` line by line.

```
point = JointTrajectoryPoint()
```

Get a new `JointTrajectroty` point.

```
point.positions = copy(positions)
```

Copy the arg `positions` into the newly created `point`'s `positions` attribute.

```
point.time_from_start = rospy.Duration(time)
```

Set `time_from_start` of `point`

```
self._goal.trajectory.points.append(point)
```

Append this newly created `point` to the list `self._goal.trajectory.points`

`copy(positions)` is used to simply copy the lists to the new `JointTrajectory` point. You can't `append()` positions directly to `self._goal.trajectory.points`. You can only `append()` `point`s.

Hope it's clear!

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-14**:
Hi Janindu,
Frist of all, thank you for your replying. After your explain it really help me to understand how to use the `copy()` and `append()`, but in the end, you mention that I can only `append() point`s, that points which one are you refer to? Are you referring to the `point.positions` ?
Thanks

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
So, `self._goal.trajectory.points` is simply a list of `JointTrajectory` points.
ie : `self._goal.trajectory.points = [p1, p2, p3]` where `p1, p2, p3` are of type `JointTrajectory`.

continued in the next comment.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
...
Each `p` ( `point`) looks like this :

```
{    
float64[] positions
float64[] velocities
float64[] accelerations
float64[] effort
duration time_from_start
}
```

Now using `copy()` you copy the `positions` passed as arguments to the `point`.

continued...

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
...
`positions` look like this:

```
positions = {
        'left':  [-0.11, -0.62, -1.15, 1.32,  0.80, 1.27,  2.39],
        'right':  [0.11, -0.62,  1.15, 1.32, -0.80, 1.27, -2.39],
   }
```

You can't append positions to `self._goal.trajectory.points` when that list expects `point`

cont.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
...
You can only append `point` to `self._goal.trajectory.points`, which is what's being done by `append()`.

Hope it's clear!

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
Wow! yes!i get that! Thank you so much! Your explain is really useful for me.